# Yammer authorization error

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, jsonp, yammer

I am getting the following error while trying to run this code:

```
        function getCurrentUser() {
        yam.platform.request({
            // yam.request({
            url: "users/current.json", //this is one of many REST endpoints that are available
            method: "GET",

            data: {},
            success: function (user) { //print message response information to the console
                console.log("User request was successful.");
                console.dir(user);
                toggleLoginStatus(true);
                $('#authResult').html('User Result:<br/>');
                for (var field in user) {
                    $('#authResult').append(' ' + field + ': ' +
                        escape(user[field]) + '<br/>');
                }

            },
            error: function (user) {
                console.error("There was an error with the request.");
            }
        });

    }
```

`Error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/users/current.json?_=1407933095976. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://brillioonline.sharepoint.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I am trying to use the following code in order to solve the error, but have no clue what token is here:

```
$.ajax(
'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me',
{
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
},
complete: function (resp) {
  console.log(resp);
},
error: function (jqXHR,  textStatus,  errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus);
}
}
 );
```

Please help me with this, i am a beginner

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to use Ajax or set the header mannually. Yammer js sdk does it for you. But if you really want to use Ajax, you can get the token from the response of `getLoginStatus` (see below)

To get current user without Ajax, make sure you have logged in. Here is an example:

```
function login() {
    yam.platform.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
          if (response.authResponse) { //if already logged in
              alert("token=" + response.access_token.token);
          } else {
              yam.platform.login(function (response) {
                  if (response.authResponse) {
                      alert("token=" + response.access_token.token);
                  }
              });
          }
    });
}
```

2. After a successful login, run your request. If it still doesn't work, run the request inside a `getLoginStatus` block:

```
yam.platform.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
          //RUN YOUR REQUEST HERE.
      } else {
          alert("something went wrong");
      }
});
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried the above code, but i am still getting the access denied error for the step 1 although the logging is active. could you please help me with this.

Comment: Response is undefined in line 2 of step 1. Currently i am loading the following js- platform_embed.js and platform_js_sdk.js.Do I need to load any other references.

Comment: platform_js_sdk.js alone should be enought. Then did you add your domain to the JavaScript origin white list on yammer? It's in: https://www.yammer.com/client_applications and go to your app --> basic info --> Installation information --> Javascript Origins

Comment: Where do we add the domain?